# Bash Scripting: How to check for active sshfs mount in dir?

Tags: bash, shell-script, mount, sshfs

If currently have this code:

```
0130: moba(){
0131:     if [ -z "$(ls -A /home/me/Documents/A/B)" ]; then
0132:         echo "Empty"
0133:         sshfs me@domain:/home/C/D /home/me/Documents/A/B/
0134:         cd /home/me/Documents/A/B/
0135:     else
0136:         echo "Not Empty"
0137:         cd /home/me/Documents/A/B/
0138:     fi
0139: }
```

Firstly, this code is copied(the if-statement part) and just checks for the contents of the dir B, is there a less hacky and more robust way to check if the mount is active and "working"?

As i have like zero experience with this, i would greatly appreciate it, if you could write the if-Cond, such that i can basically just copy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the exit status of the `mountpoint` command.

Ex.

```
steeldriver$ mountpoint ~/Documents/A/B ; echo $?
/home/steeldriver/Documents/A/B is not a mountpoint
1
```

Then

```
steeldriver$ sshfs me@192.168.1.3:/home/me/Documents ~/Documents/A/B
steeldriver@192.168.1.3's password:
steeldriver$
steeldriver$ mountpoint ~/Documents/A/B ; echo $?
/home/steeldriver/Documents/A/B is a mountpoint
0
```