# Using rm --one-file-system to only delete files on the local filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount, rm, fuse

I have a FUSE mount located in `/media/writable`, however, sometimes this FUSE mount disconnects, but some programs will still attempt to write to `/media/writable`.

When I restart the FUSE mount service, it will fail to mount because the directory is non-empty.

How can I use `rm`'s `--one-file-system` argument to ensure that when I rm `/media/writable`, it will only delete files located on the **local** filesystem, as opposed to the **fuse mounted** filesystem? There are other folders located in `/media/` so I am unable to run `rm` in the parent folder.

Am I better off moving the folder one layer down (eg. `/media/writable/mount`) so I can rm the parent folder, or is there a way of selecting which filesystem I wish to delete from?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with coreutils 8.28.

Edit: My current method is this, but I'd like to see if there's a better way to do it:
`ExecStartPre=-/bin/mountpoint /media/writable/ || /usr/bin/stat /media/writable/MOUNTED || /bin/rm/ --one-file-system -rf /media/writable/*`

Comment: I'd check out [steeldriver's mountpoint answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505169/117549)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ooh, that's an interesting one. I'll take a look, thanks!

Comment: `ExecStartPre=` should not work like that? I think you need to wrap your shell command like `/bin/sh -c " command1 || command2 || command3 "`

Comment: @sourcejedi Ah, I didn't realise that wouldn't work, I was just testing with it. I guess I was wrong saying that it was my current method, but it was the one I'd worked out that I thought would work. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to `cd` into that directory. Then even if the directory is being mounted while your clean-up script is running, you will still be seeing the old local directory (as long as you only use relative paths).

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat || exit
cd /media/writable || exit

stat -H parent .. || exit
stat -H here   .  || exit

if (( parent[device] == here[device] )); then
  # current directory is on the same device as parent
  all_files=(*(ND))
  (( $#files == 0 )) ||
    rm -rf --one-file-system --preserve-root=all -- $all_files
fi
```

Note the `D` glob qualifier to also remove hidden files, and the `--preserve-root=all` as a complement of `--one-file-system` in case some of the `$all_files` are themselves mount points for some other file systems (though [that one doesn't appear to be race-free in the current implementation](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=45371), so I would avoid `rm -rf --one-file-system --preserve-root=all /media/writable`).

That could still fail with a *"argument list too long"* error if there's a large number of files there, which you could work around by writing it:

```
print -rNC1 -- $all_files |
  xargs -r0 rm -rf --one-file-system --preserve-root=all --
```